# Происхождение слова "крепостной"

Tags: этимология

Происхождение слова "крепостной"

Answer (score 4):

От слова "крепость" суффиксальным способом. Крепостной крестьянин - это крестьянин **закрепленный** за тем или иным помещиком.

Answer (score 2):

***Крепостной*** -- от ***крепость***.

[*"**Крепостью** в древнерусском праве назывался акт, символический или письменный, утверждавший власть лица над известной вещью…"*](https://books.google.ru/books?id=J6kFe8jty3MC&pg=PA380&dq=%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%22%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX_MeqirnKAhVp9HIKHQr3C5sQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%22%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]